# AngularJS - ngOptions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select that uses an array of dealer objects. I can display a dealer name as an option, but I would like to also display the distance. e.g. "Dealer Name - 12 miles".

My select:

```
<select ng-show="dealers" ng-model="formData.dealer.dealerNumber"
ng-options="dealer.dealerNumber as dealer.name for dealer in dealers">
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions):

> select as **label** for value in array
>
> label: The result of this expression will be the label for <option> element. The expression will most likely refer to the value variable (e.g. value.propertyName).

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', ["$scope",
    function($scope) {
      $scope.dealers = [{
          dealerNumber: 1,
          name: 'd',
          distance: '123'
        }, {
          dealerNumber: 2,
          name: 'dd',
          distance: '124'
        }, {
          dealerNumber: 3,
          name: 'ddd',
          distance: '125'
        }, {
          dealerNumber: 4,
          name: 'dddd',
          distance: '126'
        }, {
          dealerNumber: 5,
          name: 'ddddd',
          distance: '127'
        }, {
          dealerNumber: 6,
          name: 'dddddd',
          distance: '128'
        }


      ];

    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select ng-show="dealers" ng-model="dealerNumber" ng-options="dealer.dealerNumber as dealer.name+'-'+dealer.distance for dealer in dealers">
  </select>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:** with using filters

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', ["$scope",
    function($scope) {
      $scope.dealers = [{
          dealerNumber: 1,
          name: 'd',
          distance: '123.5'
        }, {
          dealerNumber: 2,
          name: 'dd',
          distance: '124.6'
        }, {
          dealerNumber: 3,
          name: 'ddd',
          distance: '125'
        }, {
          dealerNumber: 4,
          name: 'dddd',
          distance: '126'
        }, {
          dealerNumber: 5,
          name: 'ddddd',
          distance: '127'
        }, {
          dealerNumber: 6,
          name: 'dddddd',
          distance: '128'
        }


      ];

    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select ng-show="dealers" ng-model="dealerNumber" ng-options="dealer.dealerNumber as dealer.name+'-'+(dealer.distance|number:0) for dealer in dealers">
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks, is there a way to have a filter on the distance to make it a whole number. Something like {{ dealer.distance | number:0 }}

Comment: @user3562751 yep you can use filter, but with parentheses, try see updated answer

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is the following :

```
    <select ng-show="dealers" ng-model="formData.dealer.dealerNumber"
                              ng-options="dealer.dealerNumber as (dealer.name + ' - ' + dealer.distance) for dealer in dealers">
    </select>
```